# Sending data by JDBC, strange case with StrictMode

Tags: java, android, jdbc

My method working only with `StrictMode`, when i delete `StrictMode`, my app after the run this method loading in the infinity... and never stop.
I don't know why, somebody can explain it ?

```
public void sending() {

    Connection co = null;
    Statement st = null;

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy po = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(po);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        co = DriverManager.getConnection(url2, user2, pass2);

        st = co.createStatement();

        Double bb = latitude;
        Double bb1 = longitude;

        String sql2 = "INSERT table (tab1, tab2) VALUES('" + bb + "', '" + bb1 + "')";
        st.executeUpdate(sql2);

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                co.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }
        try {
            if (co != null) {
                co.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your code in a thread.

Comment: Did you try to run the code in a  debugger and step through it so you can narrow down where it fails?

Comment: btw. if your SQL works that way, I want to know what Database you use. Because it should not. And you should use PreparedStatement as YCF_L said, it really is a good idea in virtually all situations.

Answer (score 1):

Your have a problem in your Query it should be :

```
"INSERT Into table (tab1, tab2) VALUES('" + bb + "', '" + bb1 + "')"
```

and not :

```
"INSERT table (tab1, tab2) VALUES('" + bb + "', '" + bb1 + "')"
```

You missed Into in your query.

---

Note

You can get syntax error or Sql injection with your way i suggest to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) it's more secure and more helpful like this :

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
                connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into table (tab1, tab2) VALUES(?, ?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, bb);
preparedStatement.setString(2, bb1);
```

Comment: my query is working properly, I checked, the problem arises when I delete StrictMode from my code

Comment: there is no error, when 'sending' calls the application stops responding

Comment: NOOOOO your query is not work you have an error in your query the syntax of Insert into is not correct so change what i do and check if your problem still exist or not you can learn here about the syntax of Insert https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp @forschool

Comment: when i add "into", still app no works, i told you, my application works perfectly, but when I remove StrictMode it stops and I do not know why

Comment: @YCF_L I assume his code fails before it reaches the SQL. That query must fail, but it is most likely not his primary problem.

Comment: thank you @AngeloFuchs yes i get it, i makes a mistake, yes i agree with you the problem happen before the execution of the query for that the OP not get sql error